# Can't iterate through JSON object

Tags: json, node.js

I'm pulling a JSON request from the politifact API:

```
request('http://politifact.com/api/v/2/statement/?format=[JSON]&order_by=-ruling_date&limit=1')
        .then(({
            data
        }) => {        
        newArticles = extractListingsFromJSON(data);
```

and parsing it with a function that the JSON is passed to

```
function extractListingsFromJSON(json) {    
    var jsonObject = json.objects
```

Outputs entire objects array

```
var headline = jsonObject[0].facebook_headline
console.log("headline:\n" + headline)
```

Outputs headline from Objects[0]

This works as intended. However, when I try to iterate through the objects array like so:

```
for (var attr in jsonObject) {
    console.log(attr+": "+jsonObject.facebook_headline);
}
```

Outputs "0: undefined"

I also tried:

```
console.log(attr+": "+jsonObject[facebook_headline];
```

Outputs nothing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you mentioned yourself `jsonObject` is an array.

```
json.objects.forEach(function (i) {
  console.log(i.facebook_headline)
})
```

Comment: This makes sense and I’m remembering forEach was my first approach... I got “forEach() is not a function of jsonObject” I’ll try this when I get home though... it’s formatted a bit differently from the way I had it

Comment: When you do, please update your post with example data of the format so I can update my answer accordingly. Cheers!

Comment: Do something like `console.log(JSON.stringify(json.objects, null, 2))`

Comment: `jsonObject.forEach(function (i) {
        console.log(i.facebook_headline);
    })`

Is working, thanks very much!

Comment: I'm happy to help!

Comment: what I was actually trying to do was `.each((i, el) => {
//Parse JSON
});` which is what I usually do to iterate through html but I guess that doesn't work with a JSON object?

Comment: If you have an object, you have an object. No need to parse again. `JSON.parse()` only works on `string` -> `object`

Comment: sorry, that was a comment inside of the block that should've read `//iterate through JSON`. As an example, inside the block I'd have `var headline = el.facebook_headline`. I see now .each is jQuery syntax -- I'm used to working with Cheerio

Answer (score 1):

You still need the attr key to iterate through the jsonObject. Try doing `attr+" :"+jsonObject[attr].facebook_headline`
 instead.

Comment: You're very close - console.log(attr+": "+jsonObject[attr].facebook_headline)

Comment: Yup, you're right! Sorry, tireness got the best of me.